# PHP 7.3 do not find curl

Tags: php, macos, curl

I am using **PHP 7.3** on **macOS Big Sur** (11.2.1).
When entering **php -version** I get the following error message:

```
    php --version                                                                                                                                                        11:12:02
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.27 (cli) (built: Feb  4 2021 17:29:32) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

How can I fix the error?
What is the cause of the error?

Comment: Not found. Probably curl isn't installed. Or check path in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Something went wrong on my computer.
When I type **php --ini**, I get the following message:

```
php --ini                                                                                                                                                            11:33:04
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```

The curl extension is already missing there.
When I look at the php.ini, the extension is activated.
[image]
Unless there are additional steps necessary?
**vi /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini**

Here is the output:

```
⋊> ~ php --ini                                                                                                                                                            11:33:04
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/curl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl, 9): image not found), /usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so (dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20180731/intl.so, 9): image not found)) in Unknown on line 0
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini
```